# lwIP: memory allocation through LWIP_MEMPOOL_ALLOC returns always NULL

Tags: c, lwip

For a company project, I have to use the lwIP library for creating a ppp connection. I have tried to adapt the code contained in the file [pppos_example.c](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/lwip.git/tree/contrib/examples/ppp). The program compiles without issues. However, when I run this snippet:

```
    ppp_sio = sio_open(0);
    if(!ppp_sio)
      {
          perror("PPPOS example: Error opening device");
          return;
      }

    ppp = pppos_create(&pppos_netif,ppp_output_cb, ppp_link_status_cb, NULL);

    if (!ppp)
     {
         printf("PPPOS example: Could not create PPP control interface");
         return;
     }
    ppp_connect(ppp, 0);
```

the program always exit before *ppp_connect* is called, as *ppp* is always NULL. The error seems to stem from the snippet at line 181 of [pppos.c](http://git.savannah.nongnu.org/cgit/lwip.git/tree/src/netif/ppp/pppos.c), as LWIP_MEMPOOL_ALLOC returns always NULL.

```
    pppos = (pppos_pcb *)LWIP_MEMPOOL_ALLOC(PPPOS_PCB);
    if (pppos == NULL) {
      return NULL;
    }
```

I have browsed through the lwIP documentation and debugged the application through Qt Creator, but could not find anything specific about this issue.
I don't know if this could be relevant, but I am running the program on a Linux Ubuntu 16.04.3 virtual machine run through VirtualBox.

What could be the reason of this behaviour?